# runtime error in storing char into a pointer value

Tags: c++

problem is in 15 and 16th line 
i am unable to store char into
a pointer pointing to a string.
the problem is same as given in
my book.?do i need to change my
compiler dev c++?
plz help.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;
void reverse(char *str)
{
    char *end=str;
    char *beg=str;
    char temp;
    while(*end)
    {
        end++;
    }
    end--;
    while(beg<end)
    {
        cout<<*beg<<" , "<<*end<<endl;
        temp=*beg;
        *beg=*end;
        *end=temp;
        beg++;
        end--;
    }
    cout<<str;
}

int main()
{
    char *str="saurabh";
    reverse(str);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have de-ja-vu. Anyway format the code

Comment: "i am unable to store char into a pointer pointing to a string" -- what happens? Do you get a compiler error?  Does your program crash?

Comment: `char str[] = "saurabh";`

Answer (score 1):

```
char *str="saurabh";
```

You cannot manipulate `"saurabh"` because it is literal.

For this you should either copy it to `char[]`,

Example,

```
char arr[20];
char *ptr = "Data";

strcpy(arr,ptr);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that you likely need to implement yourself reverse, but you can use std implementation for tests:

```
std::string s("abc");
std::reverse(s.begin(), s.end());
```